# .htaccess subdirectory to subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've written a web app for an intranet and my links don't sit with the link navigation on the live server. Joy.

I know what you're thinking : write your damned app right. Noted.

I'm wondering if there's a mod_rewrite/htaccess trick that would send me from..

```
/http://example/[admin/generic]/etc/etc2/this_stays_the_same.file
```

..to..

```
/http://example/[src/reports]/etc/etc2/this_stays_the_same.file
```

..just converting the stuff in square brackets, when I place it in the admin/generic directory.

If there is, that would be neato.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter `http://example/src/reports/...` into the browser, you can use a simple [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect /src/reports /admin/generic
```

**Update**:

If you don't want to show the `/admin/generic/...` URL in the browser bar, you must do a [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead of a redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^src/reports/(.*)$ /admin/generic/$1 [L]
```

Comment: bonus points, can you do that and keep the url the same as /src/reports/?