# Redirect webpage of any name to another webpage with same name in a different folder

Tags: .htaccess

Let there be two folders ->
"AbC" and "abc".
If the user accesses example.com/abc/file, I want to redirect him to example.com/AbC/file. This is surely to be done in the .htaccess file. I tried to do this using the RewriteRule, but cannot do it by myself as I am not quite used to this(beginner as I am ). This is very easy. Please help me do it. Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,
Ben Lind

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301542/htaccess-subdirectory-to-subdirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^/?abc/(.*)$ /AbC/$1 [L]
```

Make sure not to use the `NC` flag, as that ignores case.